# Dropdown based on one table passing to other fields using ajax laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel-5

I'm having problem with regards to selected dropdown passing fields value to other input.

Basically I have one table (plans) which have id, plan_name, price. So i want to pass price to the other input.

So I expect the output that if I selected one of the choices the price will be on the price input.

blade.php

```
<div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label">Plan</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                      <select name="plan_id" id="plan_id" class="plan" style="width:220px">
                          <option value="0">Select</option>
                          @foreach($plans as $plan)
                      <option value="{{ $plan->id}}" >{{$plan->plan_name}}</option>
                          @endforeach
                      </select>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="control-group">
                  <label class="control-label">Price</label>
                  <div class="controls">
                    <input class="plan_price" type="number" name="price" id="price">
                  </div>
               </div>
```

Here is the ajax i tried:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(document).on('change','.plan',function(){
      //console.log("hmm its change");
      var plan_id=$(this).val();
      console.log(plan_id);

      $.ajax({
        type: 'get';
        url:'{!!URL::to('findPrice')!!}',
        data:{'id':plan_id},
        dataType:'json',
        success:function(data){
          console.log("price");
          console.log(data.price);

        a.find('.plan_price').val(data.price);
        },error:function(){

        }
      })
    })
  });
```

in my controller I have this function:
I dont know if this is also correct on the where part.

```
public function findPrice(Request $request){

        $p = Plan::select('price')->where('id',$request->id)->first();
        return response()->json($p);
    }
```

Route::

```
Route::get('/findPrice','SubscriptionController@findPrice');
```

Comment: You're sending `data:{'id':price},` in your AJAX request, but I don't see where you define `price`. Should that be `data:{'id':plan_id},`? Your query and response both look alright beyond that.

Comment: I tried but still the same error I got from the beginning:: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;